# Will Bash on Ubuntu on Windows automatically run in background after starting up

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In "**Turn Windows features on or off**", if the "**Windows Subsystem for Linux(Beta)**" is checked, after Windows starting up, will the subsystem automatically run, or only run when the user opens bash.exe?

Comment: Not off-topic.  The WSL is a tool intended primarily for programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on the installation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) says that "to launch Bash on Windows, either run bash at a cmd/PowerShell command-prompt, or use the start menu shortcut".

I think it won't start automatically when Windows starts unless you modify some Windows configurations.

EDIT: you can make any program run at startup by going to "Run", entering "shell:common startup" and adding a shortcut of the program in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

This was a question two years ago. And I have a neat solution for **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Windows 10 1903**.

Press Win+R and run:

```
shell:startup
```

Create a script such ubuntu.vbs, with content:

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ws.run "wsl -d ubuntu -u root /etc/init.d/ssh start", vbhide
```

This is a neat solution to start ssh in the background when Windows starts up.

[image: Position]

[image: Script]

Reference：[Zhihu](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/47733615)